# Not able to get <abbr> tag text / timing selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, tags

[Here is the screenshot of text i want to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toCf8.png)

full link to inspect element : -

https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=4271200939570739&id=344128252278047

I want to fetch the **9 May at 11:21** from the tag please attached screenshot.

Here is the code I tried:

```
sstry_ctr = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='story_body_container']")
pptime = sstry_ctr.find_element_by_xpath(
    "./header//*[@class='_4g34 _5i2i _52we']//*[@class='_52jc _5qc4 _78cz _24u0 _36xo']/a")
ppptime = pptime.get_attribute('abbr')
print("pptime", pptime)
```

Output i am getting is "None". please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by `CSS_SELECTOR` or as a matter of fact with different locators also.

`CSS_SELECTOR` that we need to use :

```
div[data-store-id] h3+div abbr
```

How to use in code :

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=4271200939570739&id=344128252278047")
post_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-store-id] h3+div abbr"))).text
print(post_date)
```